# Is Garbage Collection time related to number of objects or size of objects?

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I am having an issue with slow garbage collection. Obviously, the more objects in heap (all else equal) will lead to longer GC time, and larger sized objects in heap will lead to longer GC times.

However I am wondering about the trade-off between object size and number of objects. For example, comparing two sets of objects that are the same total megabytes but one set has 1,000,000 objects and the other has 5 objects, which is faster to GC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object size matters very little for GC performance, whereas object *count* matters a lot. Therefore you can expect better performance for larger objects, given a fixed memory footprint of those objects.

Comment: Very clear. Thank you. I am just wondering I have heard people say very large heap size will lead to long GC. Is this true even if we just have 1 massive object to GC?

Comment: One massive object isn't realistic - large heaps allow more objects to be created between GCs and therefore those GCs are generally slower because they have more work to do.

Comment: @NickHolt Realistic or not, if you really did have just one massive object on a large heap, it would be absolutely trivial to GC it. A practical concern is that it is next to impossible to allocate an object as large as the heap, due to the partitioning into generations and other concerns.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yes, I was responding to the comment above mine about why large heaps generally lead to longer GC.

Comment: @NickHolt Fair enough, but I feel OP has a very precise question to ask: he wants to separate the effects of object count from the effects of large heap alone. That is actually a good question to ask, and there probably *are* reasons why a larger heap with the same object count would take at least a bit longer to GC.

Answer (score 4):

It is related to number of objects and complexity and number of references.  Basically, how long it takes to visit and mark everything that is "reachable".

This is because it does a [mark and sweep](http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus5/html/page424.html) where it will move from root(s) to tips and mark everything that can be reached.  Everything else is just marked as free memory, regardless of size.

**Overall GC Performance**

As mentioned in the comments by @Nick Holt, Garbage Collection would occur more frequently with larger objects as they would fill the heap faster affecting GC performance.  Clearing out a 100Gig object should still be faster than clearing out 100Gig of 10Meg objects however.

Comment: Okay so time to GC is positively related to both number and size of objects, and if you hold the aggregate size of objects to delete as constant, is the time to GC is still a monotone increasing function in number of objects?

Comment: Not size of objects, no.  Just number of objects and number of references

Comment: So a 100 gigabyte completely full heap with one object to delete will GC as quickly as a 100 megabyte completely full heap with one object to delete?

Comment: Don't larger objects fill the heap more quickly and mean GC occurs more frequently?

Comment: I would guess so but it looks like they specifically mention collection  time, not overall GC performance.  I'll extend my answer however

Comment: @NickHolt You are holding the wrong thing constant: OP's question is, for a given *total allocated memory*, what is the difference between that memory being divided into few and many objects.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik agreed, what I was trying to highlight was that there's trade-offs and that object and heap size should be considered together :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are Minor and Major GCs. Minor speed depends on new size Major depends on old size and the number of object in them. As for object size I assume that the speed of GC may be even higher when it deals with big unrefernced objects, because when GC encounters an unreferenced object it just skips it.